# MySQL stored proccedure use a row as parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am working with mysql and phpmyadmin. By the moment I have to tables: **rpsprice** and **airdrop_info**. The first table stores in a very simple way (ID, price and timestamp) the daily price of a token and the second has information about users. I am trying to update, on a daily basis, some airdrop_info columns taking as a parameter the last price registered in my rpsprice table. To achieve this goal I am using stored procedures and events..
At the moment I have a procedure that takes an input parameter, names *rps* and updates all the necessary information:

```
  BEGIN 
        UPDATE info_airdrop set unlockedRPS = unlockedRPS +  diarioUSD / rps, 
               unlockedUSD = unlockedUSD + diarioUSD, 
               dias = dias + 1 
        WHERE unlockedUSD < totalUSD;
  END
```

What I am not achieving is automating the value of rps, so that it is automatically extracted from the last record in its table.. I already tried creating a variable and using select into, I read several posts in this same forum but I always get an error.
From already thank you very much!

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved, like the procedure (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites, make sure the statements are complete and compile, don't post mere snippets), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0):

use a session variable like this

As you postet not enough information i am guessing the parameter you send

```
  BEGIN 
      SELECT price  INTO @totalUSD  FROM rpsprice  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
        UPDATE info_airdrop set unlockedRPS = unlockedRPS +  diarioUSD / rps, 
               unlockedUSD = unlockedUSD + diarioUSD, 
               dias = dias + 1 
        WHERE unlockedUSD < @totalUSD;
  END //
```

If you need more variables

```
  BEGIN 
  SELECT price, diarioUSD,rds  INTO @totalUSD,@diarioUSD,@rds  FROM rpsprice  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
        UPDATE info_airdrop set unlockedRPS = unlockedRPS +  @diarioUSD / @rds, 
               unlockedUSD = unlockedUSD + @diarioUSD, 
               dias = dias + 1 
        WHERE unlockedUSD < @totalUSD;
  END //
```